# How do I make an array display properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The homework problem I am working on is: 
Write an HTML file to create an array with 10 elements; assign each of the first 5 elements with a value which equals to its subscript; assign each of the last 5 elements with a value which equals to the addition of its subscript and 2.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Arrays</title>
        <script>
            var array1 = new Array(10); 
            for(var i = 0; i < 5; i=i+1);
                array1[ i ] = i;
            for(var i = 5; array1.length< i > 5; i=i+3);
                array1[ i ] = i;
            outputArray(array1);    
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.write(array1)  
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

All I am getting is:
,,,,,5,,,,
Where I need it to be: 
0,1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11

Comment: `array1.length< i > 5` won't do what you think it will. All you need is `i < array1.length`.

Comment: Also why `i = i + 3`??  Don't you want the second loop to iterate through `5, 6, 7, 8, 9`?

Comment: Oh also get rid of that semicolon after the `)` of the first `for` loop. And the second `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the two for loops. All you need is one for loop and then an [if conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals) to check if you are in the bottom half or top half of the array to determine its value

```js
  var array1 = new Array(10); 
  for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i=i+1){
      if (i < 5) {
        array1[i] = i;
      } else {
        array1[i] = i+2;
      }
   }

   console.log(array1);
```